# Add ManagedIdentityTokenService to a Single Node dev cluster in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a development cluster running in Azure with a single node to save costs. Some new container-based services require the `ManagedIdentityTokenService` and I'm trying to add it according to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/configure-existing-cluster-enable-managed-identity-token-service) but are prevented by ARM templates not allowing updates to single-node clusters.

Is there some workaround to recreating the entire cluster which is a bit of work? I don't care if the cluster is down while it's updating.

(The production cluster is running on five nodes so it won't be an issue upgrading there.)

The error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "SingleNodeClusterUpdateNotAllowed",
    "message": "Single node cluster update not allowed. Updates are allowed for clusters having node count equal or greater than 3.",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You'll need to [delete and recreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-windows-server) the cluster, instead of trying to update an existing one.

> If you have a development cluster, where more than one Service Fabric
>   node is on a single physical or virtual machine, you must re-create
>   the cluster with the new version.